# Get all values between '[ ]' on a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How are you guys doing?
I'd like to ask today if you could help me with a tricky question that I was unable to solve on my own.

```
I [have] strings that [are] like this.
```

I was looking for a way to get "have" and "are" and form an array with them using JavaScript. Please notice that this is an example. Sometimes I have several substrings between braces, sometimes I don't have braces at all on my strings.
My attempts focused mostly on using `.split` method and regex to accomplish it, but the closest I got to success was being able to extract the first value only.

Would any of you be so kind and lend me an aid on that?

I tried using the following.

```
.split(/[[]]/);
```

Comment: can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried using `.split(/[[]]/);` inside a for loop. Give me a minute so I can fetch the other trials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`exec()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) method in a loop, pushing the match result of the captured group to the results array. If the string has no square brackets, you will get an empty matches array `[]` returned.

```
var str = 'I [have] strings that [are] like this.'
var re  = /\[([^\]]*)]/g, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches) //=> [ 'have', 'are' ]
```

**Note:** This will only work correctly if the brackets are balanced, will not perform on nested brackets.

Comment: Thank you! It's fantastic. It did the trick wonderfully. I'd like to take the chance and apologise for my badly formatted question. I will take some time to reread Stack Overflow's guidelines. Thank you once more, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "I [have] strings that [are] like this";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

The result of `res` will be an array with the values:

```
I
[have]
strings 
that 
[are]
like 
this
```

If you want to get only values between braces, you can use the following regex expression:

```
var str = "I [have] strings that [are] like this";
var result = [];

var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var match;
while ((result = pattern.exec(str)) != null)
{
  result.push(match[1]);
}
```

This is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a7XN/76/) example for you.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with OPs question?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately this won't do. I need only the values that are inside braces.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
'I [have] strings that [are] like this.'.match(/\[([^\]]*)]/g)
```